# ExtJS 6.01 How to update tpl after store loaded

Tags: asynchronous, extjs, load, store

Let's say I have a component with tpl in HTML format, which has a variable named testname, default value is null.

A listener of beforerender calls to a function in viewController, and in this function, I need to load a store and a callback function to update the variable testname in the view, based on the store record returned.

The problem I met is the order of code execution. The function in the viewController always ended first before the store.load callback get executed. Therefore the front view will never get updated. I have tried to setup the asynchronousLoad to false but it doesn't help.

Here is the code in the viewController.

```
onViewRendering: function(theView) {
    console.log('setp 1');
    var theStore = Ext.create('App.store.Test');
    theStore.load({
        asynchronousLoad: false,
        callback: function(record) {
            console.log('setp 2');
            if (record) {
                theView.data.testname = 'updated';
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('setp 3');
}
```

Console log displays in step 1, 3, 2.

And here is the code in the View:

```
Ext.define('App.view.TestView', {
    extend: 'Ext.component',
    data:{
        testname:null
    },
    tpl:'<p>{testname}</p>',
    listeners: {
        beforerender: 'onViewRendering'
    }
})
```

Here is the store code:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.test',
    autoLoad: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: 'test.getTest'
    }
})
```

I am new to Extjs and really need some help here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update `tpl` after `store` load, you have to call `setData` method like below:

**Code snippet:**

```
onViewRendering: function(theView) {
    console.log('setp 1');
    var theStore = Ext.create('App.store.Test');
    theStore.load({
        asynchronousLoad: false,
        callback: function(record) {
            console.log('setp 2');
            if (record) {
                theView.setData({testname: 'updated'}); //setData method
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('setp 3');
}
```

Comment: It is working!! Thank you so much!! Even though the console logs are still in the wrong order, but the view data were updated correctly!

Comment: emmm, I meet another problem here. I have a button in the tpl html, and registered a linstener at afterrender. This button will be shown if a value in the store.load is true, which I used <tpl if> to verify. The problem here is now the tpl html button will be rendered but it fails to register with the afterrender function. Anyway to get this working?

Comment: I think you should ask this with the working fiddle for what you have done so far. It will be easy to get and track your problem.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I just created a fiddle and what's strange is everything works well in the fiddle, even the console log order. Anyway I will post the link here just for reference. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jdp

Thanks a lot for your help~!

Comment: I see where the problem is. The store in the fiddle is local data and in real case, the store has a direct proxy defined, which reads data from the database, and somehow there is a delay on running the code. That's why the console log order are wrong and the afterrender function is failed on register.

I guess the question comes back to how to define the store to load data synchronously.

Comment: final update (hopefully), changed the way to register the listener. Use el: {delegate:'.button-class',click:'function-name'} from afterrender:'function-name'